Zod Schema transform an array of objects to one big object
I have a couple schemas, where one uses an array of the other as a value. In example,
const ActionSchema = {id: z.string(), name: z.string(), description: z.string()} 
const PersonSchema = { id: z.string(), actions: ActionSchema.array().optional() }
type Person = z.infer<typeof PersonSchema>;


But when I want to access a Person, I want the actions property to be a single object. The conversion looks like this.
const actionsArray = [
  {action: 'run', id: '1234', description: 'run up'}, 
  {action: 'kick', id: '5334', description: 'kick it'}, 
  {action: 'punch', id: '2236', description: 'punch it'}, 
  {action: 'drop', id: '3434', description: 'drop it'}, 
];  

Become something like :

{
 run: {action: 'run', id: '1234', description: 'run up'}, 
 kick:   {action: 'kick', id: '5334', description: 'kick it'}, 
 ... 
}

So, I changed my PersonSchema to reflect it like this,
const PersonSchema = { 
 id: z.string(), 
 actions: ActionSchema.array().optional().transform((actions) => {
        return actions
          ? Object.fromEntries(actions.map((action) => [action.name, action]))
          : undefined;
      }), }


This works as intended when I output the Person.
The problem I'm having is I am getting an error in typescript when creating a new Person like this
const newPerson:Person = {
id: 'PER1234',
actions: actionsArray }

This is my error:
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{id: z.string(), name: z.string(), description: z.string()} '
The expected type comes from property 'actions' which is declared here on type '{ id: z.string(), actions: ActionSchema.array().optional() }
I know the properties are mismatched because of the transform I did on actions.
But I want the schema to accept a Actions array as input when creating a new Person, then change it to the format I want after parsing, when I choose to print or access the Person.
Sorry if it is a little confusing. Any help would be great.
I tried a lot of things to fix the error. The code "works" but typescript doesn't approve of it.
I can create the new Person using the actions array and typing it as any like this,
const newPerson:Person = {
id: 'PER1234',
actions: actionsArray as any
}

but I would like to avoid using as any if possible.

You have two schemas. One for parsing a Person, and another for the rest of your app.
function mapActions( actions: z.infer<typeof ActionSchema>) {
    return actions
          ? Object.fromEntries(actions.map((action) => [action.name, action]))
          : undefined;
}

const ParsePersonSchema = { id: z.string(), actions: ActionSchema.array().optional() }
type ParsePerson = z.infer<typeof ParsePersonSchema>;

const PersonSchema = { id: z.string(), actions: ActionSchema.array().optional().transform(mapActions) };
type Person : z.infer<typeof PersonSchema>;

function parsedPerson(person: ParsePerson): Person {
    return { ...person, actions: mapActions(person.actions) };
}


I believe this would work. I was hoping to be able to use the same schema both ways because the actual schemas are more complicated than this and it would align more consistently with how the other types and schemas are created. Thanks for your help though!
